# сделать сравнение через Comparable / Comparator

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TestFinal1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int participantQuantity = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        Participant[] participants = new Participant[participantQuantity];
        for (int i = 0; i < participantQuantity; i++) {
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(bufferedReader.readLine());
            String login = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            int solvedProblems = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            int penalty = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            participants[i] = new Participant(login, solvedProblems, penalty);
        }

        heapSort(participants);
        result(participants);
    }

    public static void heapSort(Participant[] participants) {
        List<Participant> heap = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Participant participant : participants) {
            heapAdd(heap, participant);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < participants.length; j++) {
            participants[j] = getMaxPriority(heap);
        }
    }

    private static void heapAdd(List<Participant> heap, Participant key) {
        heap.add(key);
        siftUp(heap, heap.size() - 1);
    }

    private static Participant getMaxPriority(List<Participant> heap) {
        Participant result = heap.get(0);
        heap.set(0, heap.get(heap.size() - 1));
        heap.remove(heap.size() - 1);
        siftDown(heap, 0);
        return result;
    }


    private static void siftDown(List<Participant> heap, int index) {
        int left = 2 * index + 1;
        int right = left + 1;

        if (left >= heap.size()) {
            return;
        }

        int indexLargest;
        if (right < heap.size() && compare(heap.get(left), heap.get(right))) {
            indexLargest = right;
        } else {
            indexLargest = left;
        }

        if (compare(heap.get(index), heap.get(indexLargest))) {
            swap(heap, index, indexLargest);
            siftDown(heap, indexLargest);
        }
    }

    private static void siftUp(List<Participant> heap, int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int parentIndex = (index - 1) / 2;
        if (compare(heap.get(parentIndex), heap.get(index))) {
            swap(heap, parentIndex, index);
            siftUp(heap, parentIndex);
        }
    }

    private static int compare(Participant participant1, Participant participant2) {
        if (participant1.getProblems() < participant2.getProblems()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (participant1.getProblems() > participant2.getProblems()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (participant1.getPenalty() > participant2.getPenalty()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (participant1.getPenalty() < participant2.getPenalty()) {
            return 1;
        }
        return participant1.getLogin().compareTo(participant2.getLogin());
    }

    private static void swap(List<Participant> heap, int index1, int index2) {
        Participant tmp = heap.get(index1);
        heap.set(index1, heap.get(index2));
        heap.set(index2, tmp);
    }

    private static void result(Participant[] participants) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (Participant participant : participants) {
            stringBuffer.append(participant.getLogin()).append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuffer);
    }
}

class Participant implements Comparable<Participant> {
    private String login;
    private int problems;
    private int penalty;

    public Participant(String login, int solvedProblems, int penalty) {
        this.login = login;
        this.problems = solvedProblems;
        this.penalty = penalty;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public int getProblems() {
        return problems;
    }

    public int getPenalty() {
        return penalty;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Participant that) {
        int result = Integer.compare(this.getProblems(), that.getProblems());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = Integer.compare(that.getPenalty(), this.getPenalty());
        }
        if (result == 0) {
            result = this.getLogin().compareTo(that.getLogin());
        }
        return result;
}
```

}

Comment: У меня в коде есть метод "compare" все работает нормально. Но надо этот метод сделать с помощью Comparable / Comparator. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методы [`Comparable<T>::compareTo(T other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) и [`Comparator<T>::compare(T t1, T t2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) возвращают `int`, а не `boolean` в отличие от метода `Object::equals`, чтобы можно было упорядочить несколько значений по возрастанию / убыванию, поэтому текущая реализация метода `compare(Participant p1, Participant p2)` некорректная, и её необходимо изменить следующим образом:

```java
private static int compare(Participant participant1, Participant participant2) {
    if (participant1.getProblems() < participant2.getProblems()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (participant1.getProblems() > participant2.getProblems()) {
        return 1;
    } 
    if (participant1.getPenalty() > participant2.getPenalty()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (participant1.getPenalty() < participant2.getPenalty()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return participant1.getLogin().compareTo(participant2.getLogin());
}
```

Тогда данный метод можно будет использовать для сортировки массива/списка экземпляров класса `Participant`:

```java
List<Participant> participantList = ...; // список участников
participantList.sort(MyClass::compare);
```

Также можно определить компаратор для участников в функциональном стиле, используя цепочку компараторов `Comparator::comparing` / `Comparator::thenComparing`:

```java
Comparator<Participant> sortByProblemsPenaltyDescLogin = 
    Comparator.<Participant>comparingInt(Participant::getProblems)
        .thenComparing(Participant::getPenalty, Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .thenComparing(Participant::getLogin);

participantList.sort(sortByProblemsPenaltyDescLogin);
```

---

Для использования интерфейса `Comparable` следует реализовать метод `compareTo` в классе `Participant`:

```java
class Participant implements Comparable<Participant> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Participant that) {
        int result = Integer.compare(this.getProblems(), that.getProblems());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = Integer.compare(that.getPenalty(), this.getPenalty()); // инвертировать сравнение по penalty
        }
        if (result == 0) { // сортировка по логину в алфавитном порядке
            result = this.getLogin().compareTo(that.getLogin());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

В таком случае, сортировку списка участников можно выполнить при помощи метода [`Collections::sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-), или же указать [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) при сортировке с использованием метода [`List::sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
List<Participant> participantList = ...; // список участников
// Participant реализует Comparable
Collections.sort(participantList);
// или так
participantList.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за Вашу помощь. Я сделал как вы написали, но у меня подчеркивает красным три строчки " if (right < heap.size() && compare(heap.get(left), heap.get(right))) {" "(compare(heap.get(index), heap.get(indexLargest)))" и вот эту "if (compare(heap.get(parentIndex), heap.get(index))) " Код я выложил заново, с вашими поправкамии

Comment: Методы интерфейсов `Comparable/Comparator` используются при сортировке _стандартными_ средствами Java, которые я указал в ответе (`Collections::sort, List::sort`).  У вас же используется ваша собственная реализация `heapSort`.  Либо вам не стоит применять `Comparator` вообще, либо до-опредилить методы, возвращающие `boolean`: `static boolean isLess(Participant p1, Participant p2) {return compare(p1, p2) < 0;}  static boolean isGreater(Participant p1, Participant p2) {return compare(p1, p2) > 0;}` и использовать их вместо `compare`  в вашей реализации.